# KDE 5: How to achieve "new windows follow mouse" behavior on a dual screen setup

Tags: kde, window-manager, multi-monitor, plasma, kwin

In KDE Plasma 5.19, I would like to achieve a window behavior which all new windows open on the same monitor that my cursor is on...

I have this desired behavior working at my job, in an earlier version of Plasma. I did the following for that to work:

Via the "Window Behavior" screen:

1 - Check "Active screen follows mouse" and "Separate screen focus"

2 - On "Windows rules", create a new rule that will apply for every window

3 - Add a property to the rule using "Initial position" and set it to "Force", "on main Window"

I did this exact same config on my home PC with Plasma 5.19, but it's just not working...

Answer (score 1):

In short: if you are using x11 session, make sure your app does not break placement behavior. And when it does, create rule to ignore requested geometry.

---

Some applications have their own thinking of where they want to be placed. This is crazy, but chromium (also vivaldi) window appears always in left monitor for me.
When I created a window rule with `initial placement` - `force` - `centered`, it had no effect. [At the same time, other apps are placed at correct monitor].

But when I created a rule to `ignore requested geometry` - `apply initially`, its window magically was placed correctly (on that screen from which I launched it from start menu).

This part of [documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kwin/kcontrol/windowspecific/windowspecific.pdf) explains that kde default placement settings are ignored when the app has its own thinking:

> Ignore requested geometry
> Toggle whether to accept or ignore the
> window’s requested geometry position. To avoid conflicts between the
> default placement strategy and the window’s request, the placement
> strategy is ignored when the window’s request is accepted.

Versions:
KDE Plasma: 5.23.3
Chromium: 96.0.4664.45
Vivaldi: 4.3.2439.65